# Hide Div when option from select chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that I need to hide when an option is selected in an option, below is my current html:

```
Type:<select name="Type" id="Type">
        <option value="choice">Multiple choice</option>
        <option value="image">Image/Video</option>
        <option value="click">Click Image</option>
     </select><br>
<div id="answers">  
    Correct Answer:<input type="text" name="answer"><br>        
    Wrong Answer 1:<input type="text" name="wrong1"><br>
    Wrong Answer 2:<input type="text" name="wrong2"><br>
    Wrong Answer 3:<input type="text" name="wrong3"><br>
</div>
```

So what I need is when the option with the value "click" is selected the div with the id "answers" is hidden, if either the other options are selected this div should be shown.

I am sure this can be dome with javas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for the `change` event on select, take the value `.val()` and check if it's `"click"`. If so, `show()` the `#answers`, otherwise `hide()` them.

```js
var $answers = $("#answers");
$("#Type").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "click") {
    $answers.show();
  } else {
    $answers.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#answers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type:
<select name="Type" id="Type">
  <option value="choice">Multiple choice</option>
  <option value="image">Image/Video</option>
  <option value="click">Click Image</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="answers">
  Correct Answer:
  <input type="text" name="answer">
  <br>Wrong Answer 1:
  <input type="text" name="wrong1">
  <br>Wrong Answer 2:
  <input type="text" name="wrong2">
  <br>Wrong Answer 3:
  <input type="text" name="wrong3">
  <br>
</div>
```

The no-jQuery version would be:

```
var answersElm = document.querySelector("#answers");
document.querySelector("#Type").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.value === "click") {
    answersElm.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    answersElm.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $("#Type").change(function(){
    if($("#Type").val() == "click"){
      $("#answers").css("display", "none");
    }
    else{
      $("#answers").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```